# What happen to classes added to class path in the project.properties file after the built of an independent application?

Tags: java, classpath, netbeans-platform

I'm developing a Netbeans RCP application doing some EJB connections deployed on a GlassFish server. I used the package-appclient the jar containing the needed dependencies and i added the `gf-client.jar` jar file to my class path my adding the following line to my `project.properties` file:

```
run.args.extra=-cp:a ./appclient/glassfish/lib/gf-client.jar
```

The repository is located at the root of my application.

The above works when i'm compiling/running the application within the Netbeans IDE. But now i'd like to be able to create a independent application.

What happen to the `project.properties` file after the built of the application? The extra arguments i have added to this file to add `gf-client.jar` to class path will not be viable anymore. What changes i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

the project.properties file is only used by the IDE and has no meaning when deploying application on server.

You have several options when deploying to a server:

1. Create a [manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) file which points to the required jar.
2. Copy the jar under the server lib folder, in that case it will be known to all applications running on the server
3. If your application is packed as a WAR file, put the jar under the lib folder of the application.

there are several other options but theses are the main ones.

Options 2-3 are the easiest.

Comment: Hum. I'm not deploying anything on the server, i'm talking of my client application, the one built on top of Netbeans RCP.

Comment: Are you packaging it as a jar?

Comment: I'm packaging my application as a Mac OSX application (i'm working on mac), it's not a jar.

Comment: It does not matter on what machine you pack it, eventually you should get a jar containing your class files. How do you pack it, usinf the IDE export, using ant/maven?

Comment: I use the IDE export, i guess it's an ant target somewhere. Basically, i right click on my suite and choose Package as->Mac OSX application

Comment: There should be an option to export with dependencies (Eclipse has it but I'm guessing you're using Netbeans?!).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19478/discussion-between-nathan-and-ftom2)

Answer (score 0):

Any jar file that you need to use in your NetBeans Platform application you can add to your module as a *Wrapped JAR*. You can do this by:

1. Right click on the module that needs access to this jar
2. Choose "Properties" from the context menu
3. Choose the "Libraries" Category
4. Click the "Wrapped JARs" tab
5. Click the "Add JAR" button
6. Make sure you "Clean and Build" the module before running again

If you have other modules that need access to the packages in this jar then you'll need to make the necessary packages publicly available to these other modules (not to be confused with the `public` keyword):

1. Choose the "API Versioning" Category (below the Libraries category)
2. Select the check box next to each package you want to expose to other modules
3. Make sure you "Clean and Build" the module before running again

For more detailed information see the NetBeans FAQ [DevFaqWrapperModules](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWrapperModules)

---

For reference, if you need to add command line options to your app's deployed instance you can do this by editing the app.conf file in NetBeans' harness. This file is located in `<NB_Install_Dir>/harness/etc/app.conf` and will be packaged with your application. However, editing this file will change every app.conf file for every application you build. If you build more than one application then you'll need to setup *this* application to use a custom harness [DevFaqNbPlatformAndHarnessMixAndMatch](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqNbPlatformAndHarnessMixAndMatch)